# How is it possible to leave some tags not parsed while parsing by xml.etree.ElementTree in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I need to parse xml file in Python by xml.etree.ElementTree
The xml example is:

```
<items>
    <item id="0001" type="donut">
        <name>Cake</name>
        <batters>
            <batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
            <batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>
            <batter id="1003">Blueberry</batter>
        </batters>
        <topping id="5001">None</topping>
    </item>
    <item id="0002" type="biscuit">
        <name>Biscuit</name>
        <batters>
            <batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
            <batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>
            <batter id="1004">Orange</batter>
            <batter id="1005">Banana</batter>
        </batters>
        <topping id="5006">Sprinkles</topping>
    </item>
</items>
```

The compound of `batters` could be more complex with nested structures.
Because the compound of the `batters` could change I don't want to parse every tag in `batters`.
I want to relate every `item` `id` with its `batters`. `Batters` should be presented as xml-like-string, and `item` `id` should be parsed.
So in this example I want to get the result

```
{
    '0001': '<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
        <batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>
        <batter id="1003">Blueberry</batter>',
    '0002': '<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
        <batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>
        <batter id="1004">Orange</batter>
        <batter id="1005">Banana</batter>'
}
```

The data structure could be different, it's no matter.
I couldn't find examples how to parse xml partly, i.e. parse some tags and don't parse other tags. Is it possible with xml.etree.ElementTree?

Comment: Please note in your desired result, that raw markup saved as a string is _not_ XML since it lacks a root. If you attempt to reparse such fragments with a compliant DOM library like `etree`, it should correctly fail. Consider nested dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example how to parse the XML file to the dictionary:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("your_file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

out = {}
for item in root.iter("item"):
    item_id = item.get("id")
    s = []
    for batter in item.iter("batter"):
        s.append(ET.tostring(batter).decode("utf-8").strip())
    out[item_id] = "\n".join(s)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "0001": '<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>\n<batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>\n<batter id="1003">Blueberry</batter>',
    "0002": '<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>\n<batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>\n<batter id="1004">Orange</batter>\n<batter id="1005">Banana</batter>',
}
```